# Server side React-Redux, Express with no additional ES6 and JSX syntax

Tags: javascript, express, react-redux, babeljs, reactjs

I got really interested in react-redux, read about ways of hosting actual application and came up with Express middleware  being the best for what i want to do.
I am having problem with trying to figure out how to implement server side properties for react-redux as i noticed parts of code in syntax i am new to.

Here is the code for server side.

```
import path from 'path'
import Express from 'express'
import React from 'react'
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import counterApp from './reducers'
import App from './containers/App'

const app = Express()
const port = 3000

//Serve static files
app.use('/static', Express.static('static'))

// This is fired every time the server side receives a request
app.use(handleRender)

// We are going to fill these out in the sections to follow
function handleRender(req, res) { /* ... */ }
function renderFullPage(html, preloadedState) { /* ... */ }

app.listen(port)
```

Okay, so i have no idea what this part with curly braces mean:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
```

Is it needed in anyway to use ES6/JSX/Babel syntax in server express code for React-Redux?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is no way related to the logic of your code. It is just a way to import exported submodules/functions from a library.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
```

Is same as

```
let createStore = require('redux').createStore
```

Comment: "Is same as" --- not necessary it is the same. It might be, but it is not guaranteed to be.

Comment: Should I have said "equivalent to"? That's what it is. What else will it mean?

Comment: `require('redux').createStore` means - "take a default exported object and read its createStore property". `import { createStore }` means "take the import with createStore name". The difference is that named imports not necessary belong to the default exported object, and are not interchangeable.

Comment: AFAIK if you have a named export it internally converts to that same named entry in the default export object.

Comment: That's totally not true. `export const foo = 42; export default null;` Here you have a named export `foo` that equals `42` and a default export `null` that does not have any properties at all.

Comment: `export foo;` throws error for me. Check it out here. https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=true&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAZiEBeALAZgNwCgD0OCmAHgA4gBOsCI2RpFMAJvnAIYCuANrGJxxkA

Comment: Throws me unexpected token. It needs to be `export { foo};`.

Comment: `export const foo = 42; export default null;` If `export foo;` what I typed - my apologise, I think I fixed it few seconds after.

Comment: Which translates to `module.exports = { _esModule: true, foo: 42, default: null }`. Correct me if I'm wrong. We are going down the wrong line of arguments.

Comment: Yep. And default export there is `null`. Without checking `_esModule` which is again not a part of the standard - you cannot distinguish whether it was a named export or a part of the default exported object.

Comment: So? `import { foo }` will still give you 42. Which is exactly what `require(...).foo` will give.